# How to calculate this infinite summation including cos()? Does Parseval Identity work for it?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, power-series, trigonometric-series

The problem is short: 
Find the summation of following infinite summation:

$$a(s, t) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2 \sin(\pi k t) \sin(\pi k s)}{(\pi k)^2}$$

where $t, s$ is two constant number here. I guess Parseval's theorem could work here, but I cannot find suitable $f$ till now. Could anyone give some hint or idea?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
a(u,\,v) &=\frac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(\pi k u)\sin(\pi k v)}{k^2} \\ 
 &= \frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\left(\pi k(u-v) \right )-\cos\left(\pi k(u+v) \right )}{k^2}.\\ 
\end{align*}$$

So now we just need to investigate the sum

$$S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(\pi k x)}{k^2}.$$

Fortunately this is a much easier Fourier series to deal with, and one may verify by evaluating the Fourier integrals that

$$S(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi^2}{2}x+\frac{\pi^2}{4}x^2,\qquad\text{for }0\leq x\leq2.$$

From this you can compute your sum, as

$$\begin{align*}
a(u,\,v) &=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\left(S(|u-v|)-S(|u+v|)\right) \\ 
 &=\frac{|u+v|}{2}-\frac{|u-v|}{2}-uv,\qquad\text{for }0\leq u-v \leq 2,\,0\leq u+v\leq2.
\end{align*}$$

---

As a note, I couldn't find the closed form of $S(x)$ off the top of my head. But I was able to get an idea of what it should be by taking the Mellin transform of $\cos(\pi kx)$ and then summing over the residues in $s$ of

$$\frac{\Gamma(s)\cos(\pi s/2)\zeta(s+2)}{\pi^s}x^{-s}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! if we restrict $0< u, v < 1$, I think the closed form should be $a(u, v) = min(u, v) - uv$

Comment: By the way, I'm not very familiar with Fourier integral, could you offer some more details or reference to how to calculate S(x). Thanks! :-0

Comment: The integrals you'll need to evaluate are (17), (18), and (19) shown [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html) with $L=1$. And $f(x)$ would be the closed form I gave for $S(x)$.

Comment: @0o0o0o0, I updated this answer to reflect the symmetry of the problem better.