# Is it true that $\min\{x, y\} = 2 \sum_{n \geq 1, n~\text{odd}} \frac{\sin(n x) \sin(ny)}{n^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Let $\lambda_j = \tfrac{4}{(2j - 1)^2 \pi^2}$ and $\psi_j(x) = \sqrt{2} \sin(\tfrac{2j-1}{2} \pi x)$ denote the eigenfunctions associated to the first-order Sobolev space.

It is claimed in many texts on reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces that we have
$$
\min\{x, y\} = \sum_{j \geq 1} \lambda_j \psi_j(x) \psi_j(y) = \frac{8}{\pi^2}
\sum_{n \geq 1, n~\text{odd}} \frac{\sin(\tfrac{n}{2} \pi y) \sin(\tfrac{n}{2} \pi x)}{n^2}
$$
for any $x, y \in [0, 1]$.

Equivalently, letting $t = x \pi/2, s = y \pi/2$,
$$
\min\{t, s\} = 2 
\sum_{n \geq 1, n~\text{odd}} \frac{\sin(n t) \sin(n s)}{n^2}
$$
for any $t, s \in [0, \pi/2]$.

Is there a straightforward verification of this fact? I tried applying trigonometric identities but failed to make progress in simplifying the righthand side.

Comment: Adapt to your case the method given in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3519322/305862)

Comment: Oddly, there is a cousin integral formula $\min(a, b)= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)\sin(bx)}{x^2} dx$. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4168592/305862).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the coefficients $\frac{8}{\pi^2}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ in the series, I got my clue from the Fourier series proof of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.
$$
After putting things together, here is the most direct solution to your question I have found.

We compute the cosine Fourier series of the function
$$
f(x) = 1-x \quad \text{on }[0, 2].
$$
That is, we extend the function evenly to $f(x)=1+x$ on $[-2, 0]$, and then extend the function periodically with period $4$.
Then
$$
1-x = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n \cos \frac{\pi}2 n x, \quad x\in [0, 2].
$$
We compute the Fourier coefficients by standard formulas.
\begin{align}
a_0 &= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2 (1-x)\,dx = 0,\\
a_n &= \int_0^2 (1-x)\cos\frac{\pi}2 n x\,dx\\
 &= \frac{2}{n\pi}(1-x)\sin\frac{\pi}2 n x \Big|_0^2 + \frac{2}{n\pi}\int_0^2\sin\frac{\pi}2 n x \,dx\\
&=-\frac{4}{n^2\pi^2}\cos\frac{\pi}2 n x\Big|_0^2\\
&=\frac{4}{n^2\pi^2}(1-\cos(n\pi))=\frac{4}{n^2\pi^2}(1-(-1)^n)\\
&=\begin{cases}
0 & n \text{ even},\\
\frac{8}{n^2\pi^2} & n \text{ odd}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
1-x = \frac{8}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\geq 1,n\text{ odd}} \frac{\cos\frac{\pi}2 n x}{n^2},\quad x\in [0, 2].
$$

Now we adapt this to your case. Without loss of generality, suppose that $x\geq y\in [0, 1]$. Then $\min(x, y)=y$, $x-y, x+y\in [0, 2]$.

By a standard trig identity
$$
\sin A\sin B = \frac{1}{2}\big(\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)\big),
$$
we see
\begin{align}
&\quad \frac{8}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\geq 1,n\text{ odd}} \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}2 n x)\sin(\frac{\pi}2 n y)}{n^2}\\
&=\frac 1 2 \frac{8}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\geq 1,n\text{ odd}} \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}2 n (x-y))-\cos(\frac{\pi}2 n (x+y))}{n^2}\\
&= \frac 1 2 \big((1-(x-y)) - (1-(x+y))\big)\\
&= y = \min(x, y).
\end{align}
Of course, the formula holds since $x-y, x+y\in [0, 2]$ under the assumption $x\geq y\in [0, 1]$.

If on the other hand $x\leq y\in [0, 1]$, then $x-y\in [-1, 0]$, and the above computation would continue in the last two lines as
\begin{align}
&=\frac{1}{2}(f(x-y) - f(x+y))\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\big(1+(x-y) - (1-(x+y)\big)\\
&=x = \min(x, y),
\end{align}
where we use $f(t)=1+t$ when $t\in [-2, 0]$ for $x-y$.